# custom param convertors in spring

Tags: spring, rest

Is there any custom param convertors in Spring.For example

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getEmployees/{"empName"}")
public void getEmployees(@PathVariable("empName") Employee employee)
{
}
```

The path variable which is getting from request is of type spring.Based on the given empName it will assign to Employee object.In JAX-RS we can use ParamConvertor and ParamConvertorProvider to convert.Like in JAX-RS do we have any convertors?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use custom params convertors in Spring

1 Create a converter component that implements spring Converter interface

```
@Component
public class StringToRightsModeConverter implements Converter<String, RightsMode> {

    @Override
    public RightsMode convert(String s) {
        try{
            return RightsMode.valueOf(s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return RightsMode.getByCode(s);
        }
    }
}
```

2 That's all. Spring will automatically use it for String -> RightsMode type conversion

```
@GetMapping({"/periods"})
public List<Period> periods(
        @RequestParam(required = false) RightsMode rightsMode) {
 ................................................................
}
```

[Spring 3 type conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s05.html)